# Data property inheritance in EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with the realization of data hierarchy in EF Core 3.0 (I need to use TPH).

Let's look:

```
public abstract class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract UserProfile **Profile** { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser1 : User
{
    public string ConcreteUser1Prop { get; set; }

    public override UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser2 : User
{
    public string ConcreteUser2Prop { get; set; }

    public override UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

And here we have `Profile` classes:

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string SameProp { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser1Profile : Profile
{
    public string ConcreteProfile1Prop { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser2Profile : Profile
{
    public string ConcreteProfile2Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Let it be only one `DbSet<User>` which can be used for getting data from Database.
So, I can't understand, how to say EF Core (3.0) 2 things: how to say to store `ConcreteUser*Profile` (possible, `Add` and `SaveChanges` will work properly and write concrete profile type when I add concrete type user with concrete profile type. But I don't know how to say EF Core to get the correct concrete profile type when I use `Where` or `FirstOrDefault` method?
Is this model correct in principle?

Upd.
For example, I have 2 records in my Db: `ConcreteUser1 user1`, `ConcreteUser2 user2`. So, let's have `DbSet<User> Users`, so, what will I have after the request: `var tstUser = ExampleDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault();`? What will the type of Profile variable in `tstUser.Profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution (maybe someone will use it too).

```
public class UserProfile 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ProfileRoles Role { get; set;}

    public string SameProp { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser1Profile : UserProfile
{
    public string ConcreteProfile1Prop { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser2Profile : UserProfile
{
    public string ConcreteProfile2Prop { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public UserRoles Role { get; set; }

    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser1 : User
{
    public string ConcreteUser1Prop { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteUser2 : User
{
    public string ConcreteUser2Prop { get; set; }
}

public enum UserRoles
{
    User = 0,
    ConcreteUser1 = 1,
    ConcreteUser2 = 2 
}

public enum ProfileRoles
{
    BaseProfile = 0,
    ConcreteProfile1 = 1,
    ConcreteProfile2 = 2
}
```

And It needs to be configured well in the `DbContext`:

```
public class UserStoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    DbSet<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }

    public UserStoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserStoreDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(builder =>
            {
                builder.HasDiscriminator<UserRoles>(x => x.Role)
                       .HasValue<User>(Roles.User)
                       .HasValue<Logistian>(Roles.ConcreteUser1)
                       .HasValue<Driver>(Roles.ConcreteUser2)
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>(builder =>
            {
                builder.HasDiscriminator<ProfileRoles>(x => x.Role)
                       .HasValue<UserProfile>(ProfileRoles.BaseProfile)
                       .HasValue<ConcreteUser1Profile>(Roles.ConcreteProfile1)
                       .HasValue<ConcreteUser2Profile>(Roles.ConcreteProfile2)
            });
    }
}
```

In this case when you will use the code like: `dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault()`, you also will get correct derived profile from `UserProfile`.

Maybe someone will need this solution too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HasDiscriminator` on model creating.

It will use a field to be able to decide which concrete user class you're trying map the data to.

For you it'll be something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasDiscriminator<int>("UserType")
        .HasValue<ConcreteUser1>(1)
        .HasValue<ConcreteUser2>(2);
}
```

More at:
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasdiscriminator-method

Comment: I can use it for main classes hierarchy (User -> ConcreteUser), but how to use it for Property hierarchy and use it through `DbSet<User>`?

Comment: Answer updated, with example for you. (If I understand your question correctly)

Comment: I know about Discriminator, I use it in my THP hierarchy now, but I need something which could say EF Core 3.0 to get correct profile type. For example, I have 2 records in my Db: `ConcreteUser1 user1`, `ConcreteUser2 user2`. So, let's have `DbSet<User> Users`, so, what will I have after the request: `var tstUser = ExampleDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault()`? What will the type of `Profile` variable in `tstUser.Profile`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to model (even with no EF Core), you'd need to change the type of `Profile` from `UserProfile` to `ConcreteUserProfile1`, but that's be a violation of the Liskov substitution principle, as the subclasses property type would be narrower.

Comment: please update your question with this use case scenario, which can be used to reproduce the issue.  Right now, your question relates to your conceptual understanding - That's a broad issue to address if simply posed like it is.